# Firestore manual entry for indices?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following query:

```
get invitations() {
    return this.firestore.colWithIds$(`users/${this.authProvider.currentUserId}/meetings`, (ref) => {
      return ref
      .where(`participants.${this.authProvider.currentUserId}.invitation`, '==', 'pending')
      .orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')
    });
  }
```

Everytime Firebase will generate an error that says: This query required an index and generates a link with the `currentUserId` in it. I add it to the console and everything works as expected..

However, this seems a bit too manual to maintain when users are registering. How can I generate a index that is dynamic and does not require manual entry every time a new user downloads my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query you want to do, in the general case, is not possible in Cloud Firestore with your data structure.

You will quickly run into the limit of 200 composite indexes per database, probably around your 200th user:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#indexes

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply. I have a cap of 20 participants per meeting. So I can never reach this limit. Is there any way around this... Without creating the index because I do not believe it is useful in my current scenario. (Maybe I can remove the orderBy and do a .sort on the client, is this ideal? given the 20 participants limitation I have?)

Comment: It's 200 custom indexes on your entire database, so I think you will still meet this limit.

Comment: Removing the orderBy and sorting on the client is definitely a good option since you're not using a `limit()` so you don't need server-sorting.